# Statiс variable in base templated class, C++17 usage

Tags: c++, c++17, static-linking, template-specialization

I use C++17 and I'm trying to make such classes hierarchy (simplified):

```
template<typename TChar>
class CLoggerTxtBase {
public:
    using TString = std::basic_string<TChar>;
    static TString _default_output_format;
};

using CLoggerTxt = CLoggerTxtBase<char>;
template<> std::basic_string<char> CLoggerTxt::_default_output_format{ "%F %T" };

using CLoggerWTxt = CLoggerTxtBase<wchar_t>;
template<> std::basic_string<wchar_t> CLoggerWTxt::_default_output_format{ L"%F %T" };

template<typename TChar> class CLoggerTxtFile {};
template<typename TChar> class CLoggerTxtCout {};
```

After this I have two functions that use both classes:

```
funct1(){
    CLoggerTxtCout<wchar_t> log;
}
funct2() {
    CLoggerTxtFile<wchar_t> log;
}
```

clang alerts linker errors:

```
duplicate symbol 'Logger::CLoggerTxtBase<wchar_t>::_default_output_format' in:
    CMakeFiles/test_logger.dir/src/logger_txt_file.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/test_logger.dir/src/logger_txt_cout.cpp.o
```

I have no ideas how to make single _default_output_format instance for each CLoggerTxtBase instance... Because of template I don't use .CPP-files for classes hierarchy.
It looks that it must be inlined somehow...
Thanks in advance!

**UPD** My colleague gave me an idea to use static functions that return reference to string. It's a solution, but I still would like to know is it possible to use static variables with such manner.

Comment: Why don't you `inline` them? In C++17 it is much simpler than before.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to VTT. I tried code below :

```
using CLoggerTxt = CLoggerTxtBase<char>;
template<> inline std::basic_string<char> CLoggerTxt::_default_output_format{ "%F %T" };

using CLoggerWTxt = CLoggerTxtBase<wchar_t>;
template<> inline std::basic_string<wchar_t> CLoggerWTxt::_default_output_format{ L"%F %T" };
```

That's the correct C++17 solution.